# Updater of system in PHP for customers

Tags: php, auto-update

.. and sorry for my english ..

I have something like IS written in PHP and I would like to make updating system for my customers. Here is my vision:

- I upload new version to ftp server (or web server)
- After click on update, system should compare version (done), backup old scripts (done) and make update like rsync. Delete deleted, change changed, add new files and folders.

For rsync I have to make ssh hole to my server and I don't want to do it. I found zsync, but it is designed for files, not for folder system.

Is there any easy way to do it? Some smart linux utility or some already done script in PHP?

**Thanks for answers!**

Comment: Your English is quite excellent. No need to apologize. In fact, I would have no idea if you hadn't mentioned it.

Comment: Wouldn't a system like SVN suit your needs better then a custom system?

Comment: I would like to find way how to physically replace data on customers server and I don't want to instal SVN client to customers server. But,.. If I think about it now.. It is quite easy way. I have to think about it..

Answer (score 0):

rsync can run on its own port, without any ssh involved at all: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync#Rsync Daemon

But this assume you're comfortable allowing the world at large to access your program. Do you want to restrict it to just your customers?

You could also publish your source via git; git can also run as a daemon http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html without requiring ssh. Again, it assume you're comfortable with the world at large getting your program.

Comment: Program is open source, it is OK. So, there is posibility to run rsync on server on port? I have to investigate it. But surely, it is a way. Only problem is, that it will be from now "only linux" system. Any other posibilities?

Comment: I've used the rsync client on windows before; I haven't tried the rsync daemon under windows, but it's all the same program, I would hope it would work too. :)

Comment: I would also probably use git to do this.